# Ubuntu-Touch optimization

Tags: ubuntu-touch, aquaris, meizu-mx4

I've owned a BQ Aquaris E4.5 and I now own a Meizu MX4 Ubuntu edition, and on both device, whatever the channel (I tried the stable, the rc-proposed and the devel-proposed) and Ubuntu-touch seems slow, notably when switching from a scope to another one.

Is there any schedule to optimize, or find the root cause of that "problem"?

Comment: The channels you mentioned (stable, rc, etc) determine which type of updates you get (as soon as possible vs well tested). I don't think this has much to do with the speed of your phone

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change the swappines. On my Aquarius M10 it is set to 100% by default. If you want to know what swappiness is and why it can make things slower read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swappiness.

To change swappiness you must install the terminal app from the software center, then enter the folowing commands.

```
sudo su
mount -o remount,rw /
bash -c "echo 'vm.swappiness = 30' >> /etc/sysctl.conf"
cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
```

Restart your device. (yay)

If the last command doesn't return 30 then try this:

```
nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Once you enter this command you will enter a text editor. You will see 10 black dots on an orange box in the shape of a key pad. Tap and hold that box and a menu should pop up, select the option that says "SCR". You will see some arrow keys above your keyboard, use them to navigate the text file look for a line that says: `vm.swappiness = some number` if you don't find it just add it. Replace `some number` with `30`. Now you want to save the file by taping and holding the orange dots from before, and selecting "nano". you will see some options appear above your keyboard. Tap "ctrl+o" then "ctrl+x". Restart your device.